# xsl grouping sort problem

Tags: xslt, sorting, variables, grouping

I have the following xsl template that I'm using to group my xsl. The problem I have is that I need to uppercase the @Title as currently my grouping is seeing upper and lowercase as seperate groups.

```
  <xsl:key name="rows-by-title" match="Row" use="substring(@Title,1,1)" />

    <xsl:template name="Meunchian" match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows">


            <xsl:for-each select="Row[count(. | key('rows-by-title', substring(@Title,1,1))[1]) = 1]">


                <xsl:sort select="substring(@Title,1,1)" />

                <p></p><xsl:value-of select="substring(@Title,1,1)" /><br />
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('rows-by-title', substring(@Title,1,1))">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Title" /><br/>
                    </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
```

I tried to use call-template and set a variable but xsl does not seem to like this:

```
 <xsl:key name="rows-by-title" match="Row" use="substring(@Title,1,1)" />

    <xsl:template name="Meunchian" match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows">



            <xsl:for-each select="Row[count(. | key('rows-by-title', substring(@Title,1,1))[1]) = 1]">

    <xsl:variable name="myTitle">

          <xsl:call-template name="to-upper">
            <xsl:with-param name="text">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:variable>
```

```
                <p></p><xsl:value-of select="$myTitle" /><br />
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('rows-by-title', substring(@Title,1,1))">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Title" /><br/>
                    </xsl:for-each>

            </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
```

What I am trying to achieve is meunchian grouping but without case sensitivity - hope this makes Sense!

Kieran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The way to convert lower-case letters to upper is to use the [XPath translate() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-translate)**.

Using it, one way to express the desired transformation is the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLower" select=
  "'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"
  />

 <xsl:variable name="vUpper" select=
  "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"
  />

 <xsl:key name="rows-by-title" match="Row" use=
 "translate(substring(@Title,1,1),
            'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
            )" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
     </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Meunchian" match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows">
        <xsl:for-each select=
          "Row[generate-id()
              =
               generate-id(key('rows-by-title',
                                translate(substring(@Title,1,1),
                                          $vLower,
                                          $vUpper)
                                )[1]
                       )
               ]">
            <xsl:sort select="translate(substring(@Title,1,1),
                                              $vLower,
                                              $vUpper)" />
            <p></p>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(@Title,1,1),
                                                  $vLower,
                                                  $vUpper)" />
            <br />
            <xsl:for-each select=
                             "key('rows-by-title', 
                                   translate(substring(@Title,1,1),
                                     $vLower,
                                     $vUpper)">

                <xsl:value-of select="@Title" />
                <br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the following XML document**:

```
<dsQueryResponse>
    <Rows>
        <Row Title="Agenda" />
        <Row Title="Policy" />
        <Row Title="policy" />
        <Row Title="Report" />
        <Row Title="report" />
        <Row Title="Test2" />
        <Row Title="test1" />
        <Row Title="Boo" />
        <Row Title="foo" />
    </Rows>
</dsQueryResponse>
```

**it produces the desired result**:

```
<html>
    <p/>A
    <br/>Agenda
    <br/>
    <p/>B
    <br/>Boo
    <br/>
    <p/>F
    <br/>foo
    <br/>
    <p/>P
    <br/>Policy
    <br/>policy
    <br/>
    <p/>R
    <br/>Report
    <br/>report
    <br/>
    <p/>T
    <br/>Test2
    <br/>test1
    <br/>
</html>
```

**In XPath 2.0 one will use the [`upper-case`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-upper-case)() function** to convert lower case to upper case.

Also, **grouping in XSLT 2.0 can be better expressed using the [`<xsl:for-each-group>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group)
 instruction**.